# MJML column width incorrect on Android GMAIL App

Tags: android, mjml

I have created a responsive flyer template using the latest mjml transpiler (2.0.0)

The mjml source can be viewed at http://reapic1.com/problem/flyer.txt (renamed to txt to allow opening in browser)

The resulting html created can be viewed at http://reapic1.com/problem/output.html

The resulting mobile layout looks fine in mobile width on google chrome with device emulator (see http://reapic1.com/problem/correct.jpg) but when I view it with the android gmail app, the column widths are too narrow causing all the text to wrap (see http://reapic1.com/problem/problem.png)

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Hey, I can't reproduce your issue (on a real device or using a service like Email On Acid). How did you test in Android Gmail app? If you sent the email, the service you're using might alter the HTML.

Comment: the picture above was a screenshot from my LG 3 using the android 5 default mail app.

Comment: But how did you send the email?

Comment: With thunderbird following the steps for sending raw html

Comment: That might be the issue then, as Thunderbird can alter the HTML you send. Try with a service that doesn't alter it. You can use https://putsmail.com/, it doesn't, alter it, is free and doesn't require any registration (just make sure to not check the box to inline CSS).